# Prove that certain parameterization is one to one

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, plane-curves

Let $\alpha:I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a one to one $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ curve parameterized by arc length. Im considering the function $$F(s,t)=\alpha(s)+tN(s)$$ where $\{T(s),N(s)\}$ is the Frenet dihedron. I want to find $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $F|_U$ is a parameterization (injective and injective diferential). It's straight foward to compute the diferential and see that a necessary condition is $1\neq tk(s)$, where $k(s)$ is the curvature, but I haven't managed to prove that $U=\{(s,t):tk(s)\neq 1 \}$ or anything similar does what I want.

Comment: $U$ won't be open because the domain of $\alpha$ needn't be an open interval. Or is it?You also are assuming that $k(s)$ is never zero?  Can't you use $U=\{(s,t): s\in [0,1], |t|<1/k(s)\}$, for example?

Comment: Yes, $I$ is an open interval, and meant $U=\{(s,t):s \in I,\;tk(s) \neq 1\}$ which is in fact open. You can view it as the preimage of an open set via the continuous function $tk(s)$. And about the set you suggest, I've tried things along those lines but haven't been able to make anything work. I also tried to assume that $F$ is not one-to-one and see what I could deduce from the domain, but didn't get far.

Comment: You’re right. I was addressing only the injective differential. For the injectivity you need an inverse function theorem argument with possibly shrinking neighborhoods — think about a spiral closing in on the origin …